# " Suppose you are passing or returning an array of references to mutable objects to/from a method..."

Tags: java, deep-copy, mutable

"Suppose you are passing or returning an array of references to mutable objects to/from a method.  Is it safe to make a reference copy only?  Is it safe to make a shallow copy?"

This is a study question that was given to my class and the answer is "Neither one is safe.  Only a deep copy is safe in this case."

Why is this?

Comment: The answers that have already appeared highlight that not entirely clear what you mean by "shallow copy" and "deep copy"  By "deep copy" do you mean "a new array whose elements are _the same_ as the elements of the old array (i.e., the same references)" or "a new array whose elements are references to objects which are _copies_ of the elements of the old array"?

Answer (score 2):

"Safe" can mean a lot of things, but in your particular context it is about the safety of "your" private data (the text refers to "you" as a writer of some Java class). Your private data cannot be safe if you let the client of your class access and modify it behind your back.

Therefore:

1. if you return an array of mutable objects, you must make copies of all those objects and return them in a new array;
2. if you get an array of mutable objects passed in, you must again copy them all and put them into a new array—because your client already has references to the objects he passed in.

In practice, all this is a lot of CPU work and takes memory, so it is rarely done. You either design everything to be *immutable*—or else live with the danger inherent to mutable objects.

Answer (score 1):

If your objects are mutable that means that any client with a reference to them can modify them. This can lead to race conditions, deadlocks and other un-fun behavior. However, if you make a deep copy of your objects right before using them, you will effectively be working with a snapshot of the objects. This ensures no other client is able to modify them, eliminating any concurrency or correctness concern.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case both the original array elements and the objects can be modified. In the second case only the objects can be modified, as we no longer have access to the original array. If you perform a deep copy we are working with entirely different arrays and objects, so of course it's safe.

Comment: What exactly does "safe" mean in this context?

Comment: That is something I was going to ask you. :) It depends, but in this case I'm assuming any kind of modification outside the code that was working with array and objects.